# Windows 10 taskbar - too wide, moved offscreen

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, nvidia-graphics-card, icons, intel-graphics

I've just bought myself Huawei Matebook X Pro, got it running, installed all updates, and I've noticed an interesting issue with the taskbar.

I have it set to auto-hide, on the left edge. I use something, move the cursor to the left edge, and this is what I see:

[image: taskbar-before]

As you can see, it looks like the taskbar width got set to like -100px in the X, while the right edge and the very top icons are were they should be.

The only way that I've found of returning it to normal, is to click on the "Show hidden icons" arrow icon at the bottom, and then everything snaps back to how it should be:

[image: taskbar-after]

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing PC Manager - an app that comes with the laptop. It's this icon: [PC Manager Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlqG4.png)